# The maximum modulus principles for an entire function of finite order on a horizontal strip

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

We assume that $f$ is an entire function of finite order and that $|f|\le 1$ on the boundary of the strip $S= \{z\in \mathbb{C}: \operatorname{Re} z\ge 0, -1< \operatorname{Im} z<1\}$. I would like to use a modified version of the maximum modulus principle to show that $|f(z)|\le 1$ on all of $S$.

I begin by noting that since $f$ is of finite order, there exists $C, m>0$ such that $|f(z)|\le C e^{|z|^m}$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$. As is outlined in wikipedia page of the [Phragmén-Lindelöf principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phragm%C3%A9n%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_principle), I now consider the still entire function $f(z)e^{-\varepsilon z^n}$ with $n$ satisfying $n>m$. We now consider the set $S'=S\cap \{|\arg(z)|< \pi/2n\}$. We first prove that $|f|\le 1$ on $S'$. Indeed, on $S'$ we have that $\operatorname{Re} z^n =|z|^n \cos(n\arg(z))>0$. Thus, we notice that on $S'$,
$$\left|f e^{-\varepsilon z^n}\right|\le C \exp\left(|z|^m-\varepsilon \cos(n\arg(z))|z|^n\right):=g(|z|)$$
with
$$\lim_{r\to\infty} g(r)=0.$$
Hence, we can take $R>0$ large enough such that, with $D(0,R)$ the disk of radius $R$ centered at the origin, we have
$$\left|f e^{-\varepsilon z^n}\right|\le 1$$
on $\partial D(0,R)$. Now, I would like to claim that $|f|\le 1$ on the boundary of $S'$ but I don't believe this necessarily holds. On the other hand, the reason I considered $S'$ was that on the whole of $S$, $\cos(n\arg(z))$ may be negative and then we cannot apply the P-L principle.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Yes it now appears to work for me and I have suitably edited my post.

Comment: Check this: https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/~garrett/m/complex/notes_2020-21/12a_Phragmen-Lindelof.pdf